# Performance and Implications of a PL/SQL Procedure snippet with many HTTP Requests

Tags: oracle, performance-testing, database-performance

I have a PL/SQL procedure in an Oracle database that processes data from the 'PAYMENTS' table using a cursor and performs HTTP requests to an external api to retrieve related data as xml. The procedure then parses the XML and saves data into another table. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ... IS
  CURSOR TRANSACTIONS IS SELECT ... FROM PAYMENTS WHERE ...
  C1 TRANSACTIONS%ROWTYPE;
  URL VARCHAR2(...);
  L_XMLTYPE ...
BEGIN
  URL := 'http://...'
   
  OPEN TRANSACTIONS;
  
  LOOP -- COULD BE 10000 ROWS OR MANY MORE
    FETCH TRANSACTIONS INTO C1;
    EXIT WHEN TRANSACTIONS%NOTFOUND;  
      
    MY_SCHEMA.MY_PACKAGE.MAKE_HTTP_REQUEST_TO_API(URL, C1.ID, RESPONSE_XML);

    -- PARSE RESPONSE XML
    L_XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE(LV_RESPONSE_DATA);

    SELECT
       EXTRACTVALUE(L_XMLTYPE, ...) AS ...
       ...
       INTO ...
    FROM DUAL;

    -- SAVE DATA FROM RESPONSE XML

    INSERT ...

  END LOOP;
        
  CLOSE TRANSACTIONS;
END;
```

I would like to understand the **potential performance implications of this procedure and any other related considerations**. **How can I measure them?**

Since the procedure makes HTTP requests and waits for responses before continuing with the next row.
**what specific problems could happen?**

Note: The API is designed to return the data per row and can't be changed.

I have found tools like wireshark to measure network problems, but I still don't know how to use it effectively. I have read about async and sync http calls and how the main thread could be blocked. I am not sure how it applies to oracle context though.

Comment: well whatever is calling this procedure will be blocked until it is done.

Comment: You will be dependent on network latency to the http service, and the performance of that service; they have been serialized into your process (sync) and you must wait for each call to complete. You should be able to measure the overall performance of your procedure and determine what portion of its wait time is related to the network call using AWR and ASH. Wireshark can tell you *what* is on the network, but won't really diagnose *performance* issues. You would have to independently/internally measure the performance of the HTTP service to understand that in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A network call can easily be blocked by firewall or network blocking software or a routing problem and never return. You'd want to test this to see whether sqlnet timeouts will work, but even if so this cannot be fully trusted. I've seen plenty of orphaned sessions that got lost on external network calls. This will result in indefinite hanging on to locks, undo and other resources. You'd probably want a separate asynchronous monitor process to detect this and kill the process if it gets stuck.
2. While Oracle is waiting for a http request to return, it will report its event as `TCP Socket (KGAS)`. You can see this in `v$session` for currently waiting sessions or in ASH (`v$active_session_history`) for past ones. You can either sample `v$session` or use Oracle's own 1-second sampling in ASH grouped by the wait event to see how much of your procedure is tied up waiting on network vs. CPU and other work inside the database.
3. Whenever there is a dependency on something heterogeneous outside of the Oracle database, like a network call, it is unadvisable to hold transactions open between these external calls. If you get orphaned or the outside agent simply takes forever to respond, you could be blocking others perhaps indefinitely. I would suggest adding a `COMMIT` inside the loop right after that `INSERT`. If you need transaction control so that an error should rollback *all* the inserts (unlikely I'm guessing), then a safe workaround is to use a temporary table, committing as you go, and then you can do a single `INSERT SELECT` into your final table.
4. It's also advisable to do as little as possible local work between external calls so that you can get past your dependency on the remote source as quickly as possible. This is true of database links between Oracle databases as well. The probability of a network hiccup raises the risk level of that portion of your code, so you want to use the network quickly and then be done with it. Try to postpone any heavy local work to afterwards so it is no longer vulnerable to a network problem.
5. Consider adding exception handling. If the http request (or the XML parsing) fails and raises and exception of some kind, do you want the whole program to abort, or do you want to log it and move on the next record and process what does work? If the latter you'll need to wrap your calls in an anonymous block with an exception handler:

   ```
   LOOP
     BEGIN
       // http call
       // XML parse
       // something else that could fail

       COMMIT;
     EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
         NULL; -- here you may log the error and the record that caused it. the loop will continue without aborting
     END;
   END LOOP;
   ```
6. With normal network traffic to/from a client and to/from a database link, you also have session statistics in `v$sesstat` that provide bytes transmitted to/from these two sources. But I don't believe TCP sockets through `UTL_TCP` and its higher-level packages like `UTL_HTTP`, `UTL_SMTP`, etc.. are so instrumented. My data suggests that there isn't any `v$sesstat` statistic that will track the amount of traffic. You could of course place a monitoring shell script on the OS and run `netstat` once a minute and gather TCP stats that way at the system level, but of course you wouldn't be able to distinguish between your application's work and anything else using network. You could use `SYSTIMESTAMP` before and after your http requests together with getting the `LENGTH` of each response and create your own metric to monitor throughput with from inside the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep track of the rows processed successfully. Sometimes sensitive data shouldn't be processed twice.

For example in the table **PAYMENTS**, you can add a column named **PROCESSED** and in your loop, and whenever a row is finished properly you can do :

```
update PAYMENTS set processed = 1 where id = something;
commit; -- This is very important. You may need to add (pragma autonomous_transaction)
```

And the Cursor should also be changed not to take into account the rows already processed.

```
CURSOR TRANSACTIONS IS SELECT ... FROM PAYMENTS WHERE PROCESSED = 0 and ...
```

If you do that, whenever the procedure fails for a network issue or whatever:

- You don't "lose" what has already been done ;
- You don't restart the processing from 0 ;
- You don't process any row twice in case these data are sensitive ;